# Show ANSI colors on Github README.md

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, ansi-colors

I want to convert this ugly string...

```
"\e[0;92;49mGroup::Item\e[0m | \e[0;35;49mgender\e[0m\n  \e[0;92;49mGroup::SubItem\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=22 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Juan Manuel\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=1 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=1 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"M\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=20.5 \e[0m\n    \e[0;93;49mSource::Item\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=22 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Juan Manuel\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=1 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=1 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"M\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=20.5 \e[0m\n    \e[0;93;49mSource::Item\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=31 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Leandro\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=1 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=1 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"M\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=15.5 \e[0m\n    \e[0;93;49mSource::Item\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=65 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Rodolfo\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=2 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=2 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"M\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=50.2 \e[0m\n    \e[0;93;49mSource::Item\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=8 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Francisco\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=2 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=3 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"M\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=2.5 \e[0m\n    \e[0;93;49mSource::Item\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=31 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Gustavo\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=3 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=4 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"M\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=40.5 \e[0m\n    \e[0;93;49mSource::Item\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=35 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Javier\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=3 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=5 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"M\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=25.5 \e[0m\n  \e[0;92;49mGroup::SubItem\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=64 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Susana\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=2 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=2 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"F\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=30.0 \e[0m\n    \e[0;93;49mSource::Item\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=64 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Susana\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=2 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=2 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"F\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=30.0 \e[0m\n    \e[0;93;49mSource::Item\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=33 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Virginia\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=2 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=3 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"F\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=70.1 \e[0m\n    \e[0;93;49mSource::Item\e[0m | \e[0;36;49mage=33 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mfirst_name=\"Gabriela\" \e[0m\e[0;36;49msite_id=3 \e[0m\e[0;94;49mstore_id=4 \e[0m\e[0;36;49mgender=\"F\" \e[0m\e[0;94;49msavings=45.5 \e[0m\n"
```

into this beautiful and shiny table

[image]

> Obviously, I don't want to use images...

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. [GitHub Markup](http://github.com/github/markup) uses html-pipeline to
[sanitize any HTML](http://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb), removing anything that you might use to color text,
including:

- `style` elements
- `style` attributes
- `font` elements

Note that the `color` attribute is still available, however this is not much
good because it requires the `font` element.

If you wish to add color support, voice your support for the [open issue](http://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/issues/192) at
the html-pipeline repo.